Overlaping fixed repeating tfoot and tbody on print
I have the following code producing an overlapping tfoot and tbody when printing the doc. I would like my tbody to break on page print in order for it to not overlap. The solution should be css and dynamic.


    tfoot {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
    }
    @page {
      size: A4;
      margin: 1cm;
    }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  

  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Test</th>
          <th>Test 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>



Any idea?

Have you tried changing the position: fixed to position: relative?
